# httponly cookies not set

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, keycloak

Having this setup:

- auth server (keycloak): `localhost:9990`,
- backend: `localhost:8080`,
- frontend (SPA): `localhost:3000`

Users can "login" / obtain a token on the SPA by sending their username + password to:

```
http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/w/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Then I call another url on the auth-server that should set the cookies that keycloak needs for SSO/remember-me (it should set some `HttpOnly` cookies):

```
.then(t => keycloakInstance.init({
  token: t.access_token,
  refreshToken: t.refresh_token,
  checkLoginIframe: false, // required to init with token
})
.then((authenticated) => {
  console.log('auth', authenticated); // <-- it is true
  if (authenticated) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/w/custom-sso-provider/sso', { headers: { 
    Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloakInstance.token}` } })
  // else
```

The request itself seems fine, the `Set-Cookie` occurs as I would expect; this is the response header:

[image: response header]

I would now expect them to occur in devtools > Application > cookies, but unfortunately no cookies show up. Why? And what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `credentials: 'include'` for the `fetch` call:

```
return fetch('http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/w/custom-sso-provider/sso', { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloakInstance.token}` }, credentials: 'include' })
```